# What is the value of y at the point where the line crossed the y-axis

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation of a line is y+5=6x+13

What is the value of y at the point where the line crossed the y-axis?

I've tried to figure it out but it's quite hard.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

The line crosses the $y$-axis where the $x$-component of your coordinate is $0$. So, try plug in $0$ for $x$ and solve for $y$. There you have your point where the line crosses your $y$-axis.